# Jenkins deletes workspace ,when trying to checkout from Bitbucket

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket

[image: ERROR]

Everything was working smoothly. Suddenly I see the Error while checkout from Bitbucket from jenkins -

Cloning the remote Git repository http://username@bitbucket:port/scm/projectname/appname/project.git
ERROR: Failed to clean the workspace
Java.io.IOException: Unable to delete ‘D:\Jenkins\jobs\projectname\appname\projectname\workspace.Tried 3 times (of a maximum of 3) waiting 0.1 sec between attempts.

at hudson.Util.deleteConstantRecursive(util.java.237)
at org.jenkinsci.plugin.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$2.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:502)

I am using jenkins ver-2.7

Even though I am not using deleteDir() in my jenkins pipeline script.

thanks..

Comment: What happens when you try to `Wipe Out Current Workspace` manually?

Comment: I do not have remote access of master Jenkins machine  :( its in client's environment.

Comment: Can you tell me if any of the plugins or Jenkins itself was updated?

Comment: Do you have create a fresh cove selected ? This would try to remove the previous cloned repository ?

Comment: @VighneshPai No..nothing has changed

Comment: check if my solution works for you.

Comment: @VighneshPaiI its not working for me..

Answer (score 3):

It is probably because some files in workspace have wrong owner.

Change it by running

```
sudo chown -R jenkins:jenkins /var/lib/jenkins/workspace
```

Answer (score 0):

Vighnesh Pai is on a good track, I found following article by Cloudbees describing this issue affecting only Windows nodes for users using Git client for windows the Workspace Cleanup plugin.

[Cloudbees - How can I clean the workspace in Windows agents?](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/360032353851-How-can-I-clean-the-workspace-in-Windows-agents-?page=21)

As for how to use it in a declarative pipeline, you can always use the pipeline syntax snippet generator to help you with configuring these plugin behaviors in a pipeline.

For example:

```
checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/master']], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [[$class: 'CleanBeforeCheckout']], gitTool: 'Default', submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'https://github.com/your-repository']]])
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to forcefully clean the workspace once before you checkout.

Inside your job configuration, under source code management, Git has an option called additional behavior. You can select the above-mentioned option and this error should be solved. Refer the attached image here.

[image]

Comment: I am working with groovy pipeline .. so need to use deleteDir() or cleanWs()

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. cleanWs() didn't work for you?

Comment: This is not working...and even deleteDir() giving the same error !

Comment: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Workspace+Cleanup+Plugin have you tried this plugin? It's strange that cleanWs() didn't work for you.

Comment: More strange thing is I  am just doing checkout from SCM and not even specifying deleteDir() as do not want to delete workspace..please read my question once again.. & yes started try it to delete it because I have red somewhere that might workspace got crash. And with deleteDir() also it gives the same error which I have attached snapshot in my question.

Comment: I understood your question Darshana! I'm asking you to perform cleanWs() as sometime you will land into strange things like this with groovy scripts and even with normal configs. If you have already tried this then its fine. As a last optoin, either try restarting the jenkins or loading settings from the disk from manage jenkins menu.